# Multiple conditions in vue.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js, frontend

I'm new in vue.js and I'm trying to add multiple conditions.

EDIT: First code example works. (I was very tired last night and dunno what I was thinking).

e.g.

```
if hours > 11 && hours < 18 show some text etc..
```

Here is my first code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hyL723fb/20/

Here is my second code:

http://jsfiddle.net/trcyn2qh/28/

Comment: Your first example works for me. The only confusing thing could be that the hours 1, 11, 17 and 24 are not covered with your if else as you are using > and not >=

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot >=. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you are redefining `getHoursCondition` in the computed function `getHoursCondition`. That's going to cause a problem of a name clash. You should just return the value you want from the function.

For example:

```
if (this.hours > 01 && this.hours < 11) {
        return 'Good morning'; // <-- return the value
    }
```

Here's a working fiddle (it says 'good afternoon' to me, which is correct for my time): http://jsfiddle.net/9e53pm2q/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly the problem in your code , but you can do the same thing with methods and [Lifecycle Hooks](http://Instance%20Lifecycle%20Hooks)  instead of computed properties:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 data: {
        hours: new Date().getHours(),
    getHoursCondition: '' //define the variable first
  },
  methods: {
     getHours: function () {
    if (this.hours > 01 && this.hours < 11) {
        this.getHoursCondition = 'Good morning';
    } 
    else if (this.hours > 11 && this.hours < 17) {
            this.getHoursCondition = 'Good afternoon';
}
else if (this.hours > 18 && this.hours < 24) {
            this.getHoursCondition = 'Good evening';
} else {
        this.getHoursCondition = 'something';
}
  }
},
  mounted(){
     //when the instance is mounted call the method getHours()
      this.getHours()
  }
});
```